# How can I connect two ubuntu server with L2TP v3?

Tags: vpn, tunnel, l2tp

My scenario is I want to run a VPN server on the Ubuntu server. but, because my ISP blocks the outbound connection to outside the country I have to first connect to a server in the data center, and then with that server, I must connect to the outside Ubuntu.
Fortunately, L2TP v3 is not banned in the data center to the outside. but It has to be version 3.

How can I deploy this scenario? I have ubuntu-1 with IP-1 and Ubuntu-2 with IP-2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The L2TP RFCs define two basic kinds of L2TP packets: control packets (the “control plane”), and data packets (the “data plane”). The Linux kernel’s L2TP subsystem handles the data packets for L2TPv2 and L2TPv3. The more complex L2TPv2 and L2TPv3 control packets are handled by user space programs.

ProL2TP supports L2TPv2 and L2TPv3 :

- https://prol2tp.com/

ProL2TP is from the authors of the Linux kernel’s L2TP subsystem, it was also the first implementation of L2TPv3.

I'm not aware of any free L2TPv3 implementations, only L2TPv2.

Comment: thnaks for your time

Comment: I was wrong about no free L2TPv3 implementations, e.g. there is SoftEther VPN https://www.softether.org/ and possibly others.

Comment: As far as I read, Softether can be run on windows. Is possible to run it on linux?

Comment: SoftEther runs on Windows, Linux, macOS, FreeBSD and Solaris.
Here are details of the SoftEther packages for Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=softether&searchon=names